# Superset guest token returns login page

Tags: python, embed, apache-superset

I am trying to embed the dashboard into an iframe on another site. Both the sites are on HTTP only. Here are the configs in the superset file

```
PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE_GAMMA: True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'LAX'
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE: 'Gamma'
HTTP_HEADERS = {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOWALL'}
```

The back end code is as follows:

```
myobj = {
  "user": {
    "username": "username",
    "first_name": "*****",
    "last_name": "*****"
  },
  "resources": [{
    "type": "dashboard",
    "id": "1"
  }],
  "rls": []
  
}

login = requests.post(login_url, json={"password": "Password$","provider": "db","refresh": True, "username": "username"})
login_response = json.loads(login.text)

headers = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {login_response['access_token']}"}

csrf = requests.get(csrf_url, headers = headers)

csrf_token = json.loads(csrf.text)['result']
headers_csrf = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {login_response['access_token']}",
    'Referer': csrf_url,
    'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
}
print(headers_csrf)
guest_token = requests.post(guest_token_url, json = myobj, headers = headers_csrf)

guest_token = json.loads(guest_token.text)['token']
print(guest_token)

final_url = f"http://superset.hookit.korenet.local?token={guest_token}&next=/superset/dashboard/p/jWQx9XBR4Bw/?standalone=true"
```

The backend code generates the following URL that is inserted in the iFrame on another site:

```
http://superset.domain.local?token=*************************.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Imxhc3RfbmFtZSI6IkthbnNhcmEiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRrYW5zYXJhIiwiZmlyc3RfbmFtZS****************************************Ym9hcmQiLCJpZCI6IjEifV0sInJsc19ydWxlcyI6W10sImlhdCI6MTcwNDY2MDYzNS42ODgwMDYyLCJleHAiOjE3MDQ2NjA5MzUuNjg4MDA2MiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovLzAuMC4wLjA6ODA4MC8iLCJ0eXBlIjoiZ3Vlc3QifQ.t2SZsWg66njR1He20cAcMA9mhkafuCZBqrX58jabqbo&next=/superset/dashboard/p/jWQx9XBR4Bw/?standalone=true
```

The issue is that the iFrame always shows the login page only. I tried the URL in incognito window and this also showed the login page.
Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong ? We would like to see the Dashboard as a guest user as the external users need to see the dashboard in the other site.

Thanks for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

The functionality only works when the dashboard is embedded using the supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard function.